# Javascript missing ) after argument list

Tags: php, javascript

I have this function, and I call it from PHP with onClick="login_f('.$return.')"
But in Firefox it gives me an error "javascript missing ) after argument list"
Any help?

```
  function login_f(return_v){
    email = document.login.email.value;
    email2 = document.login.email2.value;
    if(email == "" || email2 == ""){
      if(readCookie("lang") == "it_IT")
        msg('<span style="color:#D90909">Compila tutti i campi!</span>'); 
      else
        msg('<span style="color:#D90909">Fill in all fields!</span>');
    }
    else if(email != email2){
      if(readCookie("lang") == "it_IT")
        msg('<span style="color:#D90909">Le email non coincidono!</span>');
      else
        msg('<span style="color:#D90909">The emails do not match!</span>');
    }
    else{
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
      document.cookie = "email=" + email + expires + "; path=/sbm/";
      if(return_v == "" || return_v == null)
        window.location.href = "http://www.xriuk.com/sbm/";
      else
        window.location.href = return_v;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is in `$return`?

Comment: pls post the complete code for this part.. onClick="login_f('.$return.')" ..!

Comment: login_f does few action and then points the page back to the url in $return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do like:

```
echo '<a ... onClick="login_f(\''.$return.'\')">....</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (based on where it is used) `$return` (and therefore `return_v`) is a string.

If that's the case, then it needs quotes around it.

I highly recommend using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) to embed ANY kind of variable, not least because it greatly helps prevent XSS.

So your PHP becomes:

```
echo '...... onClick="login_f('.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($return),ENT_QUOTES)."');"....';
```

Comment: $return is a string containing an URI, why do I need to encode it?

Comment: Right-click and View Source. Tell me it's valid HTML.

Comment: ... Okay, now tell me that it's valid JavaScript you have there.